# firewalld: ERROR: Calling pre func <bound method Firewall.full_check_config of <class 'firewall.core.fw.Firewall'

Tags: firewall, firewalld

I got an error on `systemctl status firewalld.service` which looked like this:

```
firewalld[18072]: ERROR: Calling pre func <bound method Firewall.full_check_config of <class 'firewall.core.fw.Firewall'>(True, True, True, 'INIT', False, '', {}, [], True, True, True, False, 'off')>(()) failed: check_config_dict() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
firewalld[18072]: ERROR: Calling pre func <bound method Firewall.full_check_config of <class 'firewall.core.fw.Firewall'>(True, True, True, 'INIT', False, '', {}, [], True, True, True, False, 'off')>(()) failed: check_config_dict() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

The firewalld itself still works fine though even with this error. I'm not very familiar with how firewalld works underneath, so please help with where this error came from and how could I fix it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you are not mentioning which OS and package version you are using. But I guess it's openSUSE Leap 15.3 with package firewalld-0.9.3-150300.3.3.1. If yes, it's a known bug which is already reported.
We are working on it, already found missing patches and new version of package will be soon released.

https://bugzilla.suse.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1197911